# SiteMinder on IIS7.5 Authentication on app by app basis?

Tags: iis-7.5, siteminder

I inherited a mess of servers which host multiple applications on IIS6, protected by R6 SiteMinder.  The environment is soon going to R12, and we have also received some new servers with IIS7.5. (Lots of change, all within the next 60days.)

I am not an expert, and so am having trouble with some of the more detailed steps of configuration.  Thus far, on the new server I am able to create and apply SiteMinder to the DefaultWebSite (and everything contained within), and any custom Sites that I create.  Unfortunately in our environment, it is already set up with a handful of applications that live underneath DefaultWebSite, only some of which we desire SiteMinder protection.

In IIS6 I was able to simply add a site to SiteMinder authentication by applying the ISAPI6WebAgent.dll in the wildcard mappings.  In IIS7.5, this does not seem to work.  I follow the specific details in the installation manual and it seems like it is either an all-or-nothing situation: everything under DefaultWebSite is protected, or nothing is.

This will cause a SIGNIFICANT amount of additional work in my environment (and it also means upgrading in place is not possible, so all applications that require SiteMinder authentication will need to be migrated in the next 60 days.)  Is there ANY workaround for this?  Google has not provided me with any solutions, and my SiteMinder team is claiming "it is no longer possible with IIS7.5" to keep the environment the way it is currently set up.

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that care, if you are running under an Integrated App Pool, you can simply add and remove the SiteMinder modules to control which sites are protected by SiteMinder.  This DOES work on apps below a virtual directory - and using the config files you can both inherit protection by default, or have it unprotected and add it later by simply "Configure Native Module" and adding it back.